# Call a DLL from another DLL

Tags: c#, dll, reference, compilation, call

I'm fairly new to C# (coming from java, although the syntax is almost identical), and i'm having trouble referencing a DLL.

Im trying to reference it / call it from another DLL, in which is called from a VB interface. I can reference the DLL within the other DLL just fine, but when I try to compile it, its asking if im missing a namespace or reference.
So my questions are:

A. Can I actually reference and use DLL from another DLL (And have it compile obviously)

B. How?

Note: Using visual studio 2010. To compile I use:

```
csc /target:library /out:<dll name>.DLL <Source1.cs> <Source2>.cs
```

ect.

Thank you all in advance,

~Mitch

Comment: Just add the DLL by "Add References..." menu option. To compile, just click the compile button ( no need to type commands )

Comment: Its called build and build solution, under Build menu in case you don't have the build toolbar and icons.

Comment: To extend on @orn's commend, in specific cases you may want to alter the build order (directions easily found by googling for _build order_ and your IDE's name.)

Comment: Thanks guys (: Im newish to visual studio, so I'm still learning

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Right click project that you wish to reference dll from.  Select 'Add reference' option.  Building can be achieved from the menu at the top under 'Build'.  I know this was answered above, but I thought it would be useful to mark the question as answered.

Comment: what if i want to call the dll function which is kept somewhere inside the folder and not referenced and built..???